# Cygwin postinstall script errors (exit code 254)

Tags: windows-7, cygwin

I'm trying to install cygwin, but I'm getting the following post-install script error:

```
Package: _/base-files
    base-files-mketc.sh exit code 254
    base-files-profile.sh exit code 254
```

I can't find any useful information on this through Google.  I've found a couple other post-install error discussions that recommend deleting Cygwin and clearing the registry, rebooting, and reinstalling, which I tried with no luck.

Has anyone encountered this and if so, how can it be resolved.

EDIT: [Here's the setup log](https://pastebin.com/iCNGX8qN)

Comment: Before that you have already other issues  `dash 7004 fork: child 5240 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11` . Something is interfering with Cywgin. Usually an antivirus https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda

Comment: @matzeri I disabled my antivirus and am still having the problem

Comment: @ewok I had this problem and had to **uninstall** my antivirus (avast). Cygwin then installed correctly. I then reinstalled the antivirus (I haven't tried to add any new packages to Cygwin since).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two steps:

- disable antivirus
- disable firewall

If this help, turn on firewall and add all cygwin folders to firewall whitelist.

If not, read [this](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.fixing-fork-failures)

> ### How do I fix fork() failures?
>
> Unfortunately, Windows does not use the fork/exec model of process
>   creation found in UNIX-like OSes, so it is difficult for Cygwin to
>   implement a reliable and correct fork(), which can lead to error
>   messages such as:
>
> - unable to remap somedll to same address as parent
> - couldn't allocate heap
> - died waiting for dll loading
> - child -1 - died waiting for longjmp before initialization
> - STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
> - resource temporarily unavailable
>
> Potential solutions for the above errors:
>
> - Restart whatever process is trying (and failing) to use fork(). Sometimes Windows sets up a process environment that is even more
>     hostile to fork() than usual.
> - Ensure that you have eliminated (not just disabled) all software on the [BLODA](https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.bloda).
> - Switch from 32-bit Cygwin to 64-bit Cygwin, if your OS and CPU support that. With the bigger address space fork() is less likely to
>     fail.
> - Try setting the environment variable CYGWIN to "detect_bloda", which enables some extra debugging, which may indicate what other
>     software is causing the problem.
>
>   See [this mail](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-02/msg00797.html) for more information.
> - Force a full rebase: Run rebase-trigger fullrebase, exit all Cygwin programs and run Cygwin setup.
>
>   By default, Cygwin's setup program automatically performs an incremental rebase of newly installed files. Forcing a full rebase
>     causes the rebase map to be cleared before doing the rebase.
>
>   See /usr/share/doc/rebase/README and /usr/share/doc/Cygwin/_autorebase.README for more details.
>
>   Please note that installing new packages or updating existing ones undoes the effects of rebase and often causes fork() failures to
>     reappear.
>
>   See the [process creation](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/highlights.html#ov-hi-process) section of the User's Guide for the technical
>     reasons it is so difficult to make fork() work reliably.

Comment: I have already followed these steps with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using other mirrors?

The issue may be related to the mirror. The error code may be related to the ssh termination.

Source: [PythonAnywhere Forums](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/1389/)

Comment: I did. Ultimately it turned out to be an unlisted BLODA. I was able to get corporate support to remove it from my laptop and I now have Cygwin working.

Answer (score 0):

I have stumbled across the same issue the other day when I was trying to install Cygwin on Windows 10.

When researching the problem, I found something about an address mismatch in the setup log (sorry that I don't have the exact wording - I won't reproduce that error ...). That lead me to the idea that it might have something to do with ASLR (a technique to harden the system against malware).

So I turned off ASLR. After doing so, I could install Cygwin without problems.

As said above, this was with Windows 10. But to my best knowledge, Windows 7 also has ASLR, so this could very well be the source of your problems. You can turn it off in Windows via UI if you download EMET, or via registry ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560993/how-do-you-disable-aslr-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows-7-x64)). So you could try that and see if Cygwin then installs correctly.

Please note that I do not recommend having ASLR turned off; I am considering it as an important malware protection. However, in Windows 10, you can enable ASLR *per executable*, meaning that you can turn it on system-wide and make exceptions for the Cygwin executables. I am nearly sure that you can achieve the same in Windows 7.

In short, you could

- turn off ASLR system-wide and install Cygwin
- turn on ASLR again system-wide
- if the Cygwin installation did not fail, except the Cygwin executables from ASLR

That last step could mean creating dozens of exceptions, though, but for me, it's worth it.